# NSMutableArray replace items

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a mutable array like this:

```
[0] {
name => "Mark"
surname => "Smith" }
[1] {
name => "John"
surname => "Mayer" }
[2] {
name => "Bob"
surname => "Moltz" }
[3] {
name => "Rick"
surname => "Wayne" }
...
```

What I want and didn't get it, is to look for surname and replace it when I found Moltz.

I searched a lot, but couldn't get an answer. Seem that I only can use objectAtIndex or valueForKey, but I need to use both of them.

I will appreciate a little help. Thanks.

Comment: So each position of the array stores a dictionary? Or an object with fields name and surname?

Comment: Well you just loop through the array elements and replace the object if the value for the key matches your predicate.

Comment: Replace what? The whole dictionary (or object) / just the surname ? All instances ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the array and check that one specific key

Using NSMutableDictionary iteration

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in mutableArray) {
        NSString *value = [obj objectForKey:@"surname"];
        if ([value isEqualToString:@"Moltz"]) {
            [dict setObject:@"My new surname" forKey:value];
        }
    }
```

Using KVC

```
for (NSObject *obj in mutableArray) {
    NSString *value = [obj valueForKey:@"surname"];
    if ([value isEqualToString:@"Moltz"]) {
        [obj setValue:@"My new surname" forKey:value];
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't specify whether the nested dictionaries were mutable or immutable.

Comment: Good point. Changed the answer to use KVC

Comment: @WilliamFalcon I think the OP might benefit from seeing both your original answer, and your new one.

Comment: @WilliamFalcon `setValue:forKey:` will still fail for an immutable dictionary.

Comment: Yeah... he should probably specify it. If it is immutable he just needs to create a new one and replace that key.

Comment: Second solution works perfect!!!